# dropzonejs: acceptedFiles: "video/* doesn't accept m4v in Safari

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using a dropzone with the option

```
acceptedFiles: "video/*"
```

In Safari, when I click it, I can't select .m4v-files (works in FireFox) in the Explorer-window. However, it works via drag & drop.

Answer (score 6):

From the example above its looks like you missed a quota ("), if not, try to change the accepted files value to files extension, its should fix this:

```
acceptedFiles: ".mp4,.mkv,.avi"
```

From DropZone:

> The default implementation of `accept` checks the file's mime type or
>   extension against this list. This is a comma separated list of mime
>   types or file extensions. Eg.: `image/*,application/pdf,.psd`. If the
>   Dropzone is `clickable` this option will be used as `accept` parameter on
>   the hidden file input as well.

See more: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles